# How can I properly manage my apps urls?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a very long list of urls that my app uses to retrieve data from the server. Currently, each url has their own constant, i.e.:

```
// constants.h
extern NSString * const profileUrl;

// constants.m
NSString * const profileUrl = @"http://api.site.com/profile";
.
.
```

It's not that big of a deal, but if I wanted to change the base url, I have to go in and replace all of them in each constant manually. I would like to keep with the DRY philosophy (Don't Repeat Yourself) if I can. Is something like what I'm doing below possible.

```
// constants.h
extern NSString * const baseUrl;
extern NSString * const profileUrl;

// constants.m
NSString * const baseUrl = @"http://api.site.com/";
NSString * const profileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseUrl, @"profile"];
```

And if so, is there a standard way of handling your apps urls in an orderly fashion? What are some of the techniques that you use that make your life easier for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute easiest way to do this is with macros:

```
#define FOOBAR_BASE @"http://www.example.com/"
#define FOOBAR_API_BAZ FOOBAR_BASE "baz"
```

You can even do this with `NSString * const BarUrl = FOOBAR_BASE "baz";`.

This is fine if you have a single "the server". It gets messier when you have multiple servers which you want to access from the same app without recompiling (dev/production?).

In one of our apps that does this, we just have a giant header file, which is a lot better than literal strings littered everywhere in the inherited codebase...

Comment: This seems like the most elegant solution for my situation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
NSDictionary *profileURLS = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithValues:[NSArray yourArrayOfProfileURLS] forKeys:[NSArray yourArrayOfCorrespondingProfiles]];

NSString *baseURL = @"baseURLHere";
NSString *newURL = [baseURL stringByAppeningString:[profileURLS valueForKey: profileName]];
```

I think this should work for what you are doing if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have a base url where I keep in MyAppDelegate:

In MyAppDelegate .h

```
extern NSString * const SERVER_URL;
```

And in MyAppDelegate.m

```
NSString *const SERVER_URL = @"http://111.11.11.1";
```

Then to access it just import MyAppDelegate.h

```
NSString *url = [SERVER_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/your_request"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep them in a strings file. That way if the URL is different for a localized app, that's easy to accommodate with resource localization.

Comment: Well, not different languages *per se*.  Let's say your app is used in Japan and in the United States, and it lists some websites of interest for folks following politics in that country.  It wouldn't make any sense to have the folks in Japan see listings for American political institutions.  This isn't a great example, but the idea is that these websites might not necessarily have the same content.

Comment: I'd make the list based on country (detected with CoreLocation/IP address/MCC:MNC), possibly with a user-selectable override. This means you don't need to guess location based on language or make separate "localizations" for the many English-speaking countries (or French/Spanish/Portugese). And since you need web access anyway, you can make the list server-side so you don't need to update the app to change the list. (Also note that NSLocale ("Region Format") is possibly a better way of detecting the user's country.)